# Проверка файлов пользователей на вирусы

Tags: php, веб-программирование, безопасность, вирусы

Здравствуйте. Хочу проверять файлы пользователей на вирусы. Во время загрузки или после - не важно. Как это можно реализовать? Видел подобное на паре файлообменников. Сам нашел вот это - https://www.virustotal.com/ru/documentation/public-api/ И даже уже сделал проверку. Но наткнулся на это -

> **Usage restrictions** The public API can only be used for non-commercial purposes, always with the idea of helping the community
>   in mind. You must make sure you comply with our Best Practices, pay
>   special attention to the fact that VirusTotal should not be used for
>   antivirus comparatives. Any kind of usage is always bound by our Terms
>   of Service. In no event shall you issue any public statement, press
>   release, or use VirusTotal's logo, name or trademark on any customer
>   list or in any other manner without our prior written consent in each
>   instance. If in doubt, please do not hesitate to contact us with your
>   particular use case in order to make sure that it is compliant with
>   our terms.

Я не понял, они разрешают сделать то, что я хочу? А хочу я чтобы напротив загруженных файлов писалось найдены вирусы или нет. Так же у них лимиты на запросы. Какие еще способы сделать это есть?

Comment: Поставить на сервер АВ и сделать - не вариант?

Comment: Не особо подходит

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [ClamAV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClamAV), это свободное ПО. Довольно часто используется как раз на почтовых серверах и файлообменниках.

Развернуть его (или другой антивирус) на своем сервере, пожалуй, единственный бесплатный вариант, если нужно обрабатывать очень большое количество файлов.

Также можете посмотреть в сторону [scanii.com](https://scanii.com/) и других подобных площадок, если платные варианты подходят. Собственно, и у самого virustotal есть [платный приватный API](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/private-api/), где нет ограничения в 4 запроса в минуту.